# Karate : Getting "405 Method Not Allowed" Error when sending request with GET method

Tags: karate

I am using Karate to hit a GET end point but i am getting 405 method not allowed error.

From Karate logs :

```
1 > GET https://myendpoint.com/getInfo
1 > Content-Type: application/json
1 > Cookie: user_id=my_user;Path=/;Secure;Set-Cookie
1 > Accept: */*
1 > Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
1 > Host: myendpoint.com
1 > Connection: Keep-Alive
1 > User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/1.8.0-262)


16:32:52.457 DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 1527
1 < 405
1 < Date: Thu, 10 Feb 2022 11:02:52 GMT
1 < Server: Apache
1 < Allow: GET,HEAD,POST,OPTIONS
1 < Content-Length: 225
1 < Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method CONNECT is not allowed for the URL /.</p>
</body></html>
```

This same calls works in Postman, I even compared the auto generated headers and matched them here in Karate but no luck.

- I have used `karate.configure('ssl', {'tls': true});` if I don't add this I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException`
- I have also configured the proxy `karate.configure('proxy', 'https://proxyUrl")` without which I get `java.net.SocketException`

I have also tried this call in GoLang and it works there as well. Not sure what i am missing here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks to me your proxy is using [CONNECT method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/CONNECT) and the server side doesn't accept it for that resource.

Comment: Hi @Sergiu, thank you for the prompt response. I am using same proxy in Karate as well as in GoLang, shouldn't this fail in GoLang as well ?

Comment: A **tcpdump** should show you in all cases if CONNECT method is used in the same way.

Comment: Thank you @Sergiu, tcpdump would take some time for me.
For now, i wrote a custom Java code for the GET call.

Comment: sounds like you have a mismatch between `http`, `https` and the proxy: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+proxy+https

Comment: Hi @PeterThomas, thank you for your reply. Could you explain your above comment a bit more please. What do you mean when you say `mismatch between http, https and the proxy` ?

Comment: I can't explain more without a way to replicate. my suggestion is to try different combinations and read the other related discussions from the link I provided